# jQuery table loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run through a table and change each cell based on the row. Table example:

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <tr>
      <td><div id='A1'></div></td>
      <td><div id='A2'></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div id='A1'></div></td>
      <td><div id='A2'></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Function example (in script under body):

```
function myFunction(){
  var table = $('#myTable');
  var rows = table.find('tr');
  rows.each(function(i, r){
    var cells = r.find('td');
    if(i==1){//to edit second row, for example
      cells.each(function(j,c){
        var square = c.getChild();//attempt to get the div in the td
        square.innerHTML='html here';
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).load(myFunction);
```

The example shown is non-specific version of the actual function I'm trying to run.

To be clear, I have linked to the jQuery 2.1 CDN, so the page should be able to read jQuery.

Console shows no errors, but still does not run appear to run the function. Checking the tested row in the console shows no change to the html in the div. Any advice for this?

Comment: Try `$(document).ready`

Comment: I second the use of the `$(document).ready` call.

Comment: `cells = r.find('td');` should be `cells = $(r).find('td');` (because r isn't a jQuery object).

Comment: you could just use $(this).find

Comment: What is `getChild()`? It's not a jQuery or DOM method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version :

```
$("#myTable tr").each(function(i, r){
    if(i==1) 
    {
      $(this).find('td').each(function()
      {
         $(this).find("div").html("html here");
      });
    }
  });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/4dyph8jh/11/

Comment: That did it. Others helped, but this format really helped the most and I understand it pretty clearly. Thank you

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

When I run it I get an error on `r.find()` because `.find()` is a jQuery function and needs to be called on a jQuery object, which `r` is not. Simply wrapping it in a `$()` works.

```
function myFunction(){
  var table = $('#myTable');
  var rows = table.find('tr');

  rows.each(function(i, r){

  var cells = $(r).find('td');
  if(i==1){//to edit second row, for example
    cells.each(function(j,c){
      var square = c.getChild();//attempt to get the div in the td
      square.innerHTML='html here';
    });
  }
});
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k50o8eha/1/

You may need to do asomething similar to the `c.getChild();`

Comment: `getChild()` isn't a jQuery or DOM method, it's not clear what needs to go there.

Comment: I think it's javascript. It may not have involved the (), but I'm still pretty new to client-side in general.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#myTable');
  var rows = table.find('tr');
  rows.each(function(i, r){
    var cells = r.find('td');
    if(i==1){//to edit second row, for example
    cells.each(function(j,c){
      var square = c.getChild();//attempt to get the div in the td
      square.innerHTML='html here';
    });
    }
  });
});
```

or shorthand...

```
$(function() {

});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#myTable');
  var rows = table.find('tr');
  rows.each(function(i, r){
    var cells = $(r).find('td');
    if(i==1){//to edit second row, for example
    cells.each(function(j,c){
      var square = $(c).children('div');
      square.text('html here');
    });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table{
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>
<tr>
  <td><div id='A1'></div></td>
  <td><div id='A2'></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><div id='A1'></div></td>
  <td><div id='A2'></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

first the "id" should be unique to an element... but ok, this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myTable>tr:odd").children("div").text('html here');
});
```

If you want to put html code in the div, change text for html. if you want to specify the row then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   myRow = //set its value...
   $("#myTable>tr").each(function(idx, element){
      if(idx == myRow){
         element.children("div").text('html here');
      }
   }, myRow);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, you can try this

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/refayuyota/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
function myFunction(){
  var table = $('#myTable');
  var rows = table.find('tr');
  rows.each(function(i){
    if(i==1){//to edit second row, for example
      $(this).find('td').each(function(j){
        $(this).find('div').html('html here');        
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(myFunction);
```